# Pagination is not working in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, pagination

So I am developing this app in which i want to apply pagination to list of templates.

template objects are stored in the list.

I am displaying thumbnails of templates on the page and I want to apply pagination for this page.

So far I have tried following solution but it didn't work.

It displaying the pagination correctly but when I click on the link its not updating the contents of the page.

**list.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="homepage-header">
        <h2 class="homepage-title text-center wow fadeInDown animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInDown; -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;"> TEMPLATES </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="text-align: left">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback has-clear">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchParam" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 400 }" placeholder="Search template ..."
                    />
                    <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign form-control-feedback form-control-clear" ng-click="searchParam = '';
                      retreivePageData(0);" ng-show="searchParam" style="pointer-events: auto; "></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 30px;">
            <div class="form-inline">
                {{selectedOption}}

                    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x active" ng-if="status == true" ng-click="changeStatus();" title="Show component based templates"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-2x fa-rotate-180 inactive" ng-if="status == false" ng-click="changeStatus();" title="Show image based templates"></i>


                &nbsp;&nbsp;<button ng-click="newTemplateConfig()" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Add new template"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-fw"></i>New Template</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="homepage-ui-showcase-2-css row wow zoomIn animated" style="height: 402px;padding: 5px 0px; visibility: visible; animation-name: zoomIn; -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;">
        <div ng-repeat="(templateIndex, templateModel) in templatesList | filter:searchParam | limitTo: itemsPerPage">
            <div class="active col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mix design painting" style="display: inline-block;padding-top: 10px;"
            ng-init="visible=false" ng-mouseover="visible=true" ng-mouseleave="visible=false">
                <div class="portfolio-item shadow-effect-1 boxShadow" style="max-width: 250px;padding:0.3px;border:2px dotted  #bebede;cursor: pointer">
                    <div class="mainBadge">
                        <kbd>{{templateModel.badge}}</kbd>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-switch on="{{templateModel.type !== undefined && templateModel.type === 'Annotate'}}">
                        <div ng-switch-when="false" style="height: 130px;" ui-sref="/designer/:pageId({pageId:templateModel.id})" class="portfolio-img ">
                            <i style="opacity:0.4;padding-top:35px;padding-left:15px;margin-left: 30%;" class="fa fa-puzzle-piece fa-4x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="true" style="height: 130px;" ui-sref="annotator/:annotatedTemplateId({annotatedTemplateId:templateModel.id})"
                        class="portfolio-img ">
                            <i style="opacity:0.4;padding-top:35px;padding-left:15px;margin-left: 30%;" class="fa fa-file-image-o fa-4x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="portfolio-item-content" title="{{templateModel.name}}">
                        <h3 class="header" style="font-size: 13px;text-align: center;display:inline;">
                            {{templateModel.name}}
                        </h3>
                        <small class="pull-right" ng-show="visible" style="display: inline; padding-top: 4px">
                            <div ng-switch on="{{templateModel.type !== undefined && templateModel.type === 'Annotate'}}">
                                <div ng-switch-when="true" href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" title="Generate Communication"
                                 ui-sref="generateCommunication({mode:'A',id: templateModel.id})"
                                 ng-disabled="!templateModel.dynamic_entity"> <!--style="color:#9d9d9;"-->
                                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div ng-switch-when="false" href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" title="Generate Communication"
                                 ui-sref="generateCommunication({mode:'T',id: templateModel.id})"
                                 ng-disabled="!templateModel.dynamic_entity"> <!--style="color:#9d9d9;"-->
                                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row " style="margin-top: 10px; padding-top:0px;">
        <div class="pagination-div pull-right" style="">            
            <!--<pagination class="pull-right" total-items="templatesList.length" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination> -->            
            <uib-pagination total-items="templatesList.length" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-sm" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" boundary-link-numbers="true"></uib-pagination>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**list.controller.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('rapid').controller('HomeListController',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $window, $modal, ServiceFactory, toaster, ReadFileService, AnnotationService, AnnotateService, DocumentService) {

        $scope.templatesList = [];
        $scope.selectedOption = 'All';
        $scope.annotateTemplateMeta = [];
        $scope.rapidTemplateMeta = [];
        $scope.maxSize = 5;

        $scope.init = function() {
            $scope.status = true;
            $scope.selectedOption = "Image Based";
            $scope.retrieveTemplates($scope.status);
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
        };

        $scope.changeStatus = function(){
            $scope.status = !$scope.status;
            $scope.retrieveTemplates($scope.status);
        };

        $scope.retrieveTemplates = function(selectedOption) {
            $scope.templatesList = [];

            if(selectedOption) {
                $scope.selectedOption = "Image Based";
                $scope.fetchAnnotationTemplates("Annotate");
            } else {
                $scope.selectedOption = "Component Based";
                $scope.fetchRapidTemplates("Rapid");
            }
        };

        $scope.fetchAnnotationTemplates = function(selectedOption) {
            AnnotateService.get().$promise.then(function(result) {
                $scope.annotateTemplateMeta = result[0];
                console.log('Annotated template count :: ' + result[0].length);
                if (selectedOption === 'All') {
                    $scope.fetchRapidTemplates(selectedOption);
                } else {
                    $scope.prepareTemplateList(selectedOption);
                }
            });
        };

        $scope.fetchRapidTemplates = function(selectedOption) {
            ServiceFactory.PagesService.getAllPages().$promise.then(function(result) {
                $scope.rapidTemplateMeta = result[0];
                console.log('Rapid template count :: ' + result[0].length);
                $scope.prepareTemplateList(selectedOption);
            });
        };

        $scope.prepareTemplateList = function(selectedOption) {
            $scope.itemsPerPage = 1;
            var getPaginatedTemplateList = 'getList';
            $scope.currentPage = 0;
            if (selectedOption === 'Annotate') {
                $scope.annotateTemplateMeta.forEach(function(annotate) {
                    var templateObject = {};
                    templateObject = { id: annotate.id, name: annotate.name, type: "Annotate", dynamic_entity:annotate.dynamic_entity, badge:"Image Based" };
                    $scope.templatesList.push(templateObject);
                });

            } else if (selectedOption === 'Rapid') {
                $scope.rapidTemplateMeta.forEach(function(rapidTemplate) {
                    var templateObject = {};
                    templateObject = { id: rapidTemplate._id, name: rapidTemplate.name, type: "Component", dynamic_entity:rapidTemplate.pageObj.entity, badge:"Component Based" };
                    $scope.templatesList.push(templateObject);
                });
                //alert('Rapid count '+selectedOption + $rootScope.rapidTemplateMeta.length);
            } else {
                $scope.annotateTemplateMeta.forEach(function(annotate) {
                    var templateObject = {};
                    templateObject = { id: annotate.id, name: annotate.name, type: "Annotate", dynamic_entity:annotate.dynamic_entity, badge:"Image Based"  };
                    $scope.templatesList.push(templateObject);
                });
                $scope.rapidTemplateMeta.forEach(function(rapidTemplate) {
                    var templateObject = {};
                    templateObject = { id: rapidTemplate._id, name: rapidTemplate.name, type: "Component", dynamic_entity:rapidTemplate.pageObj.entity, badge:"Component Based"  };
                    $scope.templatesList.push(templateObject);
                });

                $scope.totalItems = $scope.templatesList.length;
                $scope.maxSize = 5;
            }
            //$scope.retreivePageData(0);


        };

        $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
            $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
        };


        $scope.pageChanged = function() {
            alert('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);

            });
        };




        $scope.newTemplateConfig = function (size) {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: false,
                    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                    templateUrl: 'scripts/app/home/modal/template.modal.html',
                    controller: 'TemplateModalCtrl',
                    size: size,
                    resolve: {templateModel: function () {
                            return null;
                        },
                        title: function () {
                            return 'Create New Template';
                        },
                        templateType: function() {
                            if($scope.status) {
                                return 'Annotate';
                            } else {
                                return 'Rapid'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                modalInstance.result.then(function (saveAnnotatedTemplateConfig) {
                    alert('modal result')
                    //$scope.saveAnnotatedTemplateConfig(saveAnnotatedTemplateConfig.templateConfigModel);
                }, function () {
                    console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                });
            };


        $scope.init();

    });
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Please provide some inputs on this.

Comment: why not use ui-grid ? http://ui-grid.info/

Comment: @VinoDang can you provide any inputs on how to use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ui-grid` directive to solve your pagination problem.

Please refer to the [ui-grid API](http://ui-grid.info/).

Checkout these 2 plunkers :

1. [Plunker 1](https://plnkr.co/edit/1Ij0ecBEM3xZAfFYInK0?p=preview)
2. [Plunker 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/yZrXbLr6D2NA6A24HkQZ?p=preview)